# Roll up resultset SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data generated like this

```
RowNumber   Firmware   value1   value2
    1          1          5      NULL
    1          1         NULL    NULL
    1          1         NULL    NULL
```

Any idea how to group this to get a single row using TSQL?

The output should be

```
RowNumber Firmware  value1 value2
    1        1          5      NULL
```

The rows with NULL values for 'value1' and 'value2' should be eliminated.

Comment: are the ones mentioned above the only columns in the table?

Comment: Is this a result from a query? can you post the generating SQL?

Comment: There are other columns. This is just a sample data. The columns RowNumber, firmware remains not changed, but the names of the other columns changes based on the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not

```
...
where 
          not value1 is null
      or  not value2 is null
```

In this way you eliminate the rows with NULL values for value1 and value2 and obtain only one row without using group by.

Comment: Shouldn't `and` be `or`? This retrieves rows if both values are not null.

Comment: As the user says "NULL values for 'value1' and 'value2'" I intend that both must be not null; that's why I used AND.

Comment: This query would not retrieve (5, null) row.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
        RowNumber, 
        FirmWare, 
        MAX(Value1) as Value1, 
        MAX(Value2) as Value2 

from    Table

Group by 
        RowNumber, FirmWare
```